# validate two xml with a single schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two different xml, I would like to know how I can validate each of them with a single schema (xsd). this schema must be valid for two types of xml.

e. g.:

**file1.xml**

```
<product>all</product>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<data>data all</data>
```

Thanks!.

Comment: The purpose of a schema is to validate that a file matches a specification. These are two completely different XML formats.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, so what? You can validate both of them with same XSD. Just you have to merge two different XSDs into one. Check Petru's answer.

Comment: Yes I know if *can* be done. I'm just questioning whether it *should* be done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="product" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="data" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

...or as complicated as having three files, one (the one XSD you want) which includes file1.xsd and file2.xsd.