# Are separate request and response XSDs required for an XML rest API?

Tags: xml, rest, xsd

We are building a rest api that can support requests in both json or xml.  We are also asked to build XSDs to validate the xml.  Are we supposed to write two different XSDs, one for the request XML and the second for the response XML?

Assuming I have the following resource with GET and POST methods on it:

```
/questions/
```

The GET will return all the questions while a POST will create a question.  Do I need 4 XSDs for the above case?

1. XSD for GET request
2. XSD for GET response
3. XSD for POST request
4. XSD for POST response

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

if all of the 4 messages have different formats (which most likely are) then yes, you need 4 definitions too.

now, XSDs *can* be merged. The bigger question is whether they *should*. XSDs should be mered in one when they share some common sub-component. if all the components are independent then they should better be independent too. But again if you have compelling reasons to merge your 4 XSDs then technically you can.

ref:

1. [validate two xml with a single schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008664/validate-two-xml-with-a-single-schema)
2. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=merge+xsd